# PHP session resets every request

Tags: php, windows, session, session-variables

I'm experiencing a strange issue with the PHP session. I can store values and everything until the end of the request. As soon as a new request is created, a new session file is created with a new session and data loss of the previous session as a result.

I have installed both php and apache manually on a Windows 7 machine. The session.save_path setting is set to null, but the files are being written to: C:\Windows\Temp. The session files are present there and have the actual values in them so I don't think that this is a permission issue.

Note that session_start() is being called at the very start of the php file that handles the request. This is not a code issue as I have used dummy code to verify the behavior on a different machine with a xampp server. There everything works fine.

Comment: Could the issue come from the browser being used, such as its cookie settings?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but no, I have enabled cookies in the browser.

Comment: Output the session id on each page to see if it changes, and if it does, it is a cookie problem which could have different causes. (`echo session_id()`)

Comment: You should probably look at the `session` section of `phpinfo()`.  If everything looks good there, then you'll have to look at your browser's cookies.